# What could be preventing me from waking my desktop from hybrid sleep with kb/mouse?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, mouse, wake-up

I have an MSI Codex R desktop.

I have enabled hybrid sleep in the power plan (balanced, what it regularly runs in).

I have set the check for the various mouse and keyboard entries in device manager that would allow keyboard and mouse to wake the machine.

I have run query through powercfg to see what wakeup triggers exist. I see keyboard and mouse in there.

Yet... I still have to use the power button on the case to activate the machine when I hibernate or sleep (which should be hybrid sleep if I have configuration right). The keyboard and mouse seem to do nothing.

What am I missing? Is there BIOS settings I should be looking for related to wake or security?

Motherboard appears to be an MSI H410M PRO (MS-7C89) according to system info. My keyboard is a Logitech G513 Carbon (Logitech GHub installed). My mouse is a logitech wireless mouse.

Thoughts? What additional info can I provide in an edit?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution.

The issue lay in the BIOS settings for wakeup.

The MSI BIOS in the Codex 9 R has an advanced tab (at the top of the screen, there is a toggle for Easy Mode and Advanced - you want to be in Advanced).

The MSI BIOS has USB setup under advanced but that's for enable/disable USB ports. That's NOT for dealing with wake/sleep options.

Further down in the advanced tab you see an entry that mentions Wake functions. Select that entry. You will then see the things that can wake up your machine and whether it is BIOS controlled or OS. The default is BIOS controlled and everything disabled. There are entries for old-style legacy keyboards and mice, but mine are both USB devices, so what fixed mine was choosing the USB device entry in the list of Wake sources and Enabling it.

Then be sure to exit the BIOS with saving of the new settings. Then restart the machine and you can wakeup with keyboard and mouse in USB ports.

Many articles to solve mouse/keyboard wake up and hybrid sleep don't mention the BIOS angle (there are a lot of steps to check even within windows - check mice and keyboards' power management tabs (accessing these peripherals in Device Manager) and if you want (as I did) the protection of Hibernate but the convenience of Sleep) to enable Hybrid Sleep, that's in the Power Plan under advanced. So it can take a fairly thorough dive to get all the ducks lined up - device manager, power plan, BIOS settings, and so on. But most articles focused on the Windows side don't mention the BIOS side.

Lastly, if you are like me and want mouse clicks to activate the machine but NOT mouse movement (my computer desk is on a wooden floor that sometimes experiences vibration which can wake the machine up with me nowhere in sight), that can sometimes be resolved (without totally disabling mouse wake up) in the software from the mouse manufacturer (my Logitech software helped me solve that problem).